# Itertools chain with class instance attribute

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is it possible to call `itertools.chain` (or `itertools.chain.from_iterable`) on a list of objects and get an iterator over keys of a dict in each object?

For example, with the class:

```py
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, values):
        self.mydict = values


list_of_objects = [MyClass({'a':1, 'b':2}), MyClass({'b':1, 'c':1}]

# Desired output: ['a', 'b', 'b', 'c']
```

I know that to get a list of the keys in all the objects, you can do

```py
[key for object in list_of_objects for key in object.mydict]
```

But is there a way to do it with `itertools` without defining `__iter__()`?

With `__iter__()`, could just do `return(iter(self.mydict))`, but I'd rather not (either __iter__ is already defined for another purpose, or it clutters up the class)

Comment: If `__iter__` is already defined to mean something else, then changing the behavior of iteration *specifically when `itertools.chain` is the context* is a terrible idea and a maintenance and debugging nightmare.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: `chain` just chains together two pre-existing iterators; you still have to define what it means to iterate over an instance of `MyClass` using `MyClass.__iter__`.

Comment: Maybe what you want is `chain.from_iterable(object.mydict for object in list_of_objects)`.

Comment: @chepner perfect! I'll accept that if you make it an answer

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I have a bunch of objects that use `collections.Counter`, and I wanted to get a count of the keys in the counters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So apparently I'm an idiot. Thanks to chepner, the syntax I was looking for was:

```py
itertools.chain.from_iterable(object.mydict for object in list_of_objects)
```

which created an iterator over the dictionaries, and let `chain.from_iterable` collect the keys of the dictionaries.